# Is it possible to convert a single System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase image (any type) to a bitmap object?

Tags: c#, bitmap

OK, so as the title suggests, I am attempting to convert a single `System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase` posted image (any type) to a bitmap object. I basically need to do this in order to close the object after I save the file.

Here is my code so far:

```
var PortraitImage = Request.Files["PortraitImageSelector"];
string FileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(PortraitImage.FileName);
string PortraitImageFullLocation = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(_VirtualPath), FileName);
string PortraitImageURL = string.Format("{0}/{1}", _VirtualPath, FileName);

using (var bmp = new Bitmap(PortraitImageFullLocation))
{
    bmp.Save(PortraitImageFullLocation);
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run this I get an exception stating the following:

```
{"Parameter is not valid."}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2147024809
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Parameter is not valid."
    ParamName: null
    Source: "System.Drawing"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename)\r\n   at johneschultz.Areas.Admin.Controllers.EmployeeController.Edit(EmployeeViewModel EmployeeData) in Z:\\_Profile Storage\\Projects\\johneschultz\\johneschultz\\Areas\\Admin\\Controllers\\EmployeeController.cs:line 552"
    TargetSite: {Void .ctor(System.String)}
```

Comment: What is `PortraitImageFullLocation` contains & how the image looks like (I mean the size/dimension of uploaded image)? Possibly you're hitting memory hard limit (i.e. the image memory allocation exceeds available machine's RAM) or scan line size limit.

Comment: For now, until I can get it to work, no limit on size or dimensions. After I can get a successful save/close, then I will start locking it down. but in regards to the variable mentioned, it is the physical location on the filesystem as to where the file will reside.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto if there is a better way so that the image gets saved and closed so that the file system does not keep its handles open, I am all ears :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the `HttpPostedFileBase` as a `BitMap`, simply use the `InputStream` because `BitMap` has a constructor which takes a `Stream`:

```
using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(this.Request.Files[0].InputStream))
{
    bmp.Save("whatever.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
}
```

Comment: ok, so what is the easiest way to make this a file type less implementation? Or in other words, I could upload any type, TIFF, GIF, JPG, JPEG, etc...

Comment: OK... this works to a certain point. If I try and run the code a second time, I get an error stating that the file is locked by another process. I was under the impression by using the `using` block, once the block was done or disposed of, the file would be closed and therefore "closed" any ideas as to how to "close" this file after "saving" it to the filesystem?